# Error for finding Symbol for method bound(int) on Android Studio, not sure where this problem comes from

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.2

So I was using Android Studio to create a simple "Famous Quotes" App and used most of the information on a tutorial video that showed how to complete a mini project like this. Unfortunately for me though I ended up getting this persistent error that I was not sure of solving. I tried to do things such as enabling auto imports for libraries, syncing with gradle, invalidating cache and restarting and cleaning the build with no success as a result.

What can I do to resolve this issue? I tried to find a library for this "bound" online but did not get a proper solution for it.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.technologyquotes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Random;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.view.View;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random random = new Random();

    TextView textQuote;
    Button showQuoteButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textQuote = findViewById(R.id.textQuote);
        showQuoteButton = findViewById(R.id.showQuoteButton);

        showQuoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                displayQuote();
        }
    });
        displayQuote();
    }

    protected void displayQuote(){
        int randNum = random.nextInt( bound: (6+1) - 1) + 1;
        String randQuote = "";

        switch(randNum){
            case 1 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote1);
                break;
            case 2 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote2);
                break;
            case 3 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote3);
                break;
            case 4 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote4);
                break;
            case 5 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote5);
                break;
            case 6 :
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote6);
                break;
        }
        textQuote.setText(randQuote);
    }
}
```

```
//Part that keeps breaking the code:
random.nextInt( bound: (6+1) - 1) + 1;
```

Output:
[image]
Note: *The output may show a different error but that is because I added a colon to "bound". Thought that could fix it as shown in the video as I did not spot that but it just made things worse.*

Video used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQc_fSgZwyI

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it seems that the "bound" was actually not supposed to be there; removed it for testing and the program actually worked successfully.